# in Jenkins, how do I compare versions of a file, the one in previous build with the current build?

Tags: jenkins

I am using Git as SCM, but I would prefer not to tag the code, so I'd rather use Jenkins to find out if one file has changed from one build to another , and read the content. 
of course, I would want to do this from the current build.

Answer (score 0):

You should try set up an scm browser server such as fisheye or p4web, and set up the perforce plugin to talk to it. That will provide links to the diffs for each file in the changelog.

Hope it help